# How to enable XAML Code Outlining in Microsoft Expression Blend?

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend

I'm working on a WPF project in Visual Studio 2012 and it gives a great flexibility of Code Outlining (in almost all languages it supported), as shown in screen shot of XAML:
[image]

But it seems that Microsoft Expression Blend v5 is not equipped with this flexibility, as shown in following screen shot of Blend XAML editor:
[image]

And I can't find any option to enable this code outlining.

**Is there something I'm missing or it is not there in Blend?**

Comment: Sorry, but this functionality is not yet in Blend, though I would imagine it may be something to look forward to in a future release.

Comment: I don't find any reason for avoiding this. I thought, blend inherited Visual Studio Code Editor and so as its functionality. :(

Comment: Sort of, it got some of the intellisense features etc for the editor, but then in retrospect studio got its designer since Cider kind of sucked. I imagine they'll become more cross-usability friendly in the future but for now, it is what it is. I generally run both VS and Blend since each has their strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing same as well i.e. Blend on one monitor, VS on other. Well, hoping for best in future..